# Issue in Generating new linux file

Tags: linux, vlookup

I am trying to just perform a vlookup from file 1 to file 2 using linux commands whereas i am getting proper results in wrong format.

To make it more clear,

File 1 :

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBAX test1_test  test3   test2   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4
```

File 2 :

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBAX
```

Desired Output :

```
  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBAX   test1_test  test3   test2   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4
```

Code I used :

```
FNR==NR{s=$1; sub(".*"$2,"");a[s]=$0; next} a[$1]{OFS = "\t"; FS = "\t"; print $0 a[$1]}
```

Output I got :

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBAX_test    test3   test2   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4
```

There goes some mis-alignment and due to which i am not able to process the file. I want the data in file 1 exactly in file 2 if the lookup result succeeds. Please, help me on this

Answer (score 1):

No need for `awk`, there is `join` command:

```
join -t$'\t' file1 file2
```

So, given your original inputs, you should now see:

```
http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00006IBAX test1_test  test3   test2   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4   test4
```

### How this works

Excerpt from `man join`:

> For  each pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a line to standard output.  The default join  field  is  the  first,  delimited  by whitespace.

- `-t` specifies delimiter, in your case from your `awk` code and text files, looks like you are aiming to deal with tab-delimited files
- Since we don't want default whitespace as delimiter, we need to specify tab. But there is a trick to tabs, due to a quirk of `join` in that if we specified `-t '\t'`, `join` seems to see `\t` as literally two characters `\` and `t`, and gives an error.
- So to specify tab, one way, is to do a literal tab, type `-t '` then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>tab</kbd> to insert a literal tab, then `'`
- or, what I feel is simpler, as we have done here, use C-style escaped tab `-t$'\t'`